# How can I get a list of other users in the current excel sheet?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I am the author of an Excel add-in that loads data from an internal api. What I want to do is avoid having many users run the `StreamingInvocation`s concurrently to reduce load on my api and reduce updates on the sheet.

Want I want to do is detect all of the users in the current sheet and only let the "first" user run the functions and let the others skip updating the sheet. Is there a way for me to get the list of users in the current sheet?

Comment: Try the unique() function. then check for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature: get users in the work sheet, you requested, is not a part of the product. You can add your request here:[Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions).